# Google Publisher Tag loads synchronously despite async=true

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have some Google Publisher Tag code for an affiliate network. As far as I can tell, the code says it's supposed to load asynchronously. However, GTMetrix says that it is loading synchronously. GTMetrix also warns me of this 15 times, even though there are only 5 Google Publisher Tags.

The error message is "BA.com loads https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js synchronously." As I said, this same error message is repeated 15 times.

Is there something obviously wrong here? I've included the header script for all five ads as well as the script in the widget area where just one of the ads is displayed.

//* Header Script

```
   <!-- GPT Async -->
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var gptadslots = [];
        var googletag = googletag || {};
        googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
        (function() {
            var gads = document.createElement('script');
            gads.async = true;
            gads.type = 'text/javascript';
            var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
            gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
            var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
        })();
    </script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
            var mapping = googletag.sizeMapping().
            addSize([768, 0], [728, 90]).
            addSize([0, 0], [300, 250]).
            build();

            gptadslots[0] = googletag.defineSlot('/1019006/BA0', [[728, 90], [300, 250]], 'div-gpt-ad-1452116728891-0').defineSizeMapping(mapping).addService(googletag.pubads());
            gptadslots[1] = googletag.defineSlot('/1019006/BA1', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1452116728891-1').addService(googletag.pubads());
            gptadslots[2] = googletag.defineSlot('/1019006/BA2', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1452116728891-2').addService(googletag.pubads());
            gptadslots[3] = googletag.defineSlot('/1019006/BA3', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1452116728891-3').addService(googletag.pubads());
            gptadslots[4] = googletag.defineSlot('/1019006/BA4', [[728, 90], [300, 250]], 'div-gpt-ad-1452116728891-4').defineSizeMapping(mapping).addService(googletag.pubads());

            googletag.pubads().setTargeting('blogname', ['BA']);
            googletag.pubads().enableAsyncRendering();
            googletag.enableServices();
        });
    </script>
```

//* Sidebar

```
<div class="sidebar-ad-widget"><!-- /1019006/BA1 -->
<div id="div-gpt-ad-1452116728891-1" style="height:250px; width:300px; margin:auto;">
<script type="text/javascript">
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1452116728891-1'); });
</script>
</div></div>
```